# TypeScript require dependencies after gulp-concat

Tags: typescript, gulp, gulp-concat, gulp-typescript

I have a simple TypeScript project which is made up of two files:

**helloworld.ts**

```
export class HelloWorld {
  static printHelloWorld(): void {
    console.log('Hello World');
  }
}
```

and **main.ts**

```
import { HelloWorld } from "./helloworld";
HelloWorld.printHelloWorld();
```

I'm using gulp to build the project, with `gulp-typescript` as TypeScript compiler. Everything works fine since I decide to bundle both compiled files into a single one with `gulp-concat`. This is my build task:

**gulpfile.js**

```
var paths = {
  tscripts: {
    src: ['app/src/**/*.ts'],
    dest: 'app/build'
  }
};

gulp.task('build', function () {
  return gulp
    .src(paths.tscripts.src)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(ts())
    .pipe(concat('main.js'))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.tscripts.dest));
});
```

The build process ends up with no errors, but when I run the program with `node main.js` this is what I got:

`Error: Cannot find module './helloworld'`

In fact the compiled .js tries to resolve a dependency that, after gulp-concat, is in the same file:

```
"use strict";
var HelloWorld = (function () {
    function HelloWorld() {
    }
    HelloWorld.printHelloWorld = function () {
        console.log('Hello World');
    };
    return HelloWorld;
}());
exports.HelloWorld = HelloWorld;

var helloworld_1 = require("./helloworld");
helloworld_1.HelloWorld.printHelloWorld();
```

How can I tell gulp that all the classes I'm importing in the source should be in a single file in the build?
Should I have to use any other gulp plugin? Or just have to setup correctly the TypeScript compiler?

Comment: What is your `paths.tscripts.src`?

Comment: I didn't paste all of the gulpfile.js, `paths.tscripts.src` It's an array of paths containing the source *.ts, `paths.tscripts.dest` is the directory where the build goes.

Comment: I'll ask again, what is your `paths.tscripts.src`? Please paste it

Comment: Sorry I wasn't understanding. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

To fix it, you can stop using `exports.HelloWorld` with `require("./helloworld")` and started using `gulp`, `gulp-concat`, `gulp-typescript` with `/// <reference path=` includes:

**packages.json**

```js
{
  "scripts": {
    "gulp": "gulp main"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/gulp": "^4.0.6",
    "@types/gulp-concat",
    "@types/gulp-typescript",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-resolve-dependencies": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-typescript": "^6.0.0-alpha.1",
    "typescript": "^3.7.3"
  }
}
```

**src/someimport.ts**

```js
class SomeClass {
    delay: number;
}
```

**src/main.ts**

```js
/// <reference path="./someimport.ts" />

someclass = new SomeClass();
someclass.delay = 1;
```

This `main` gulp task (on `gulpfile.js`) targets only the `src/main.js` file, resolving all its `/// <reference path=...` include references. These includes are know as `Triple-Slash Directives` and they are used only for transpilers tools to combine files. In our case, they are used explicitly by `.pipe(resolveDependencies({` and by typescript itself when checking the file for missing types, variables, etc.

1. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html
2. [When do I need a triple slash reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22684802/when-do-i-need-a-triple-slash-reference)

Refer to https://github.com/ivogabe/gulp-typescript#api-overview if you would like to customize the `var tsProject = ts.createProject` call and not use a `tsconfig.json` file or override its parameters.

**gulpfile.js**

```js
var gulp = require("gulp");
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var resolveDependencies = require('gulp-resolve-dependencies');

var ts = require("gulp-typescript");
var tsProject = ts.createProject("tsconfig.json");

gulp.task("main", function() {
  return gulp
    .src(["src/main.ts"])
    .pipe(resolveDependencies({
      pattern: /^\s*\/\/\/\s*<\s*reference\s*path\s*=\s*(?:"|')([^'"\n]+)/gm
    }))
    .on('error', function(err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    })
    .pipe(tsProject())
    .pipe(concat('main.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("build/"));
});
```

If you wold like to target all your type script project files instead of only `src/main.ts`, you can replace this:

```js
  return gulp
    .src(["src/main.ts"])
    .pipe(resolveDependencies({
    ...
// -->
  return tsProject
    .src()
    .pipe(resolveDependencies({
    ...
```

If you do not want to use `typescript`, you can use this simplified `gulpfile.js` and remove all `typescript` includes from `package.json`:

**gulpfile.js**

```js
var gulp = require("gulp");
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var resolveDependencies = require('gulp-resolve-dependencies');

gulp.task("main", function() {
  return gulp
    .src(["src/main.js"])
    .pipe(resolveDependencies({
      pattern: /^\s*\/\/\/\s*<\s*reference\s*path\s*=\s*(?:"|')([^'"\n]+)/gm
    }))
    .on('error', function(err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    })
    .pipe(concat('main.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("build/"));
});
```

**packages.json**

```js
{
  "scripts": {
    "gulp": "gulp main"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-resolve-dependencies": "^3.0.1"
  }
}
```

Then, after running the command `npm run gulp`, the file `build/main.js` is created with the following as its contents:

**build/main.js**

```js
class SomeClass {
}
/// <reference path="./someimport.ts" />
someclass = new SomeClass();
someclass.delay = 1;
```

Which allows me to include it in the browser with the `script` tag, after serving the `build` directory files:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            console.log(someclass.delay);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Related questions:

1. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/gulp.html
2. [Can I use the typescript without requireJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36710768/can-i-use-the-typescript-without-requirejs)
3. [Gulp simple concatenation of main file that requires another JS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52338233/gulp-simple-concatenation-of-main-file-that-requires-another-js-file)
4. [Client on node: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined)
5. [How can typescript browser node modules be compiled with gulp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47318837/how-can-typescript-browser-node-modules-be-compiled-with-gulp)
6. [Concatenate files using babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38381621/concatenate-files-using-babel)
7. [How to require CommonJS modules in the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576001/how-to-require-commonjs-modules-in-the-browser)
8. [Is there an alternative to Browserify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34438378/is-there-an-alternative-to-browserify)