# Simple concatenation of main file that requires another JavaScript file using Gulp.js

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have a simple file:

#### File *main.js*

```
'use strict';
const somefile = require('somefile')

// class MyClass ...
// some js
```

I want to use [Gulp.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulp.js) to create a minified file that has the code from **somefile.js** included too. But for some reason, I can't find a way to do this. Inside my minified file I have **require('somefile')**, not the full code.

#### File *gulpfile.js*

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const minify = require('gulp-minify');
const babel = require('gulp-babel');
const include = require("gulp-include");
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const jsImport = require('gulp-js-import');
const resolveDependencies = require('gulp-resolve-dependencies');

gulp.task('default', () =>
    gulp.src('src/main.js')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(resolveDependencies({
          pattern: /\* @requires [\s-]*(.*\.js)/g
        }))
        .pipe(jsImport({hideConsole: true}))
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['@babel/env']
        }))
        .pipe(minify({
            ext: {
                min: '.min.js'
            }
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
);
```

I've tried with **gulp-concat** too.

I'm missing something, but not sure what. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

In the resolveDependencies pipe you copied the default regex pattern which the [gulp-resolve-dependencies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-resolve-dependencies) will use to find any `require` statements in the code.  But your `require` looks very different than the documentation example.  Yours:

```
const somefile = require('somefile')
```

So try this pattern:  `pattern: /\.*require\s*\('(.*)'\)/g`

That should capture the file inside the parentheses (which is then automatically passed to the path resolver function). And then concat those files.

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const minify = require('gulp-minify');
const babel = require('gulp-babel');

// const include = require("gulp-include");  you don't need this

const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

// const jsImport = require('gulp-js-import');  you don't need this

const resolveDependencies = require('gulp-resolve-dependencies');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('default', () =>
    gulp.src('src/main.js')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(resolveDependencies({
          pattern: /.*require\s*\('(.*)'\)/g
        }))

         // added the following:
        .pipe(concat('a filename here'))

        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['@babel/env']
        }))
        .pipe(minify({
            ext: {
                min: '.min.js'
            }
        }))

         // added the following:
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('some destination folder for the soucemaps'))

        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
);
```

I haven't been able to test this but it should help.

Comment: Your version works. Only problem is that I have to put somefile.js into the same folder as main.js. But somefile.js is a module. How can I get that module in an elegant way and not put the file in the same folder or write const somefile = require('../node_modules/somefile/somefile.js')

Comment: There is another option, besides 'pattern', and that is 'resolvePath' where you could create a function that takes the regex match and the original target file - your 'src/main.js' and constructs and returns the actual path to the required file.  So the 'node_modules' part could be joined to the path in that function and needn't be in the require statement for example.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-resolve-dependencies#optionsresolvepath It all depends on your file structure how much you could abstract out of the require statement and into your own resolver function.

Comment: In any case, there should be no need for the required files to be in the same folder as src as long as you have a good relative path to them in the require statement or create it in the resolver function.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if you found it helpful.