# webpack - remove "webpackBootstrap" code

Tags: webpack

I am using WebPack to concat js files and output to a dist folder.  All this seems to work, however my problem is that I want to concat all the js files without extra webpack boostrap code

```
/******/ (function(modules) { // (/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap)......
```

Is there anyway to prevent webpack from adding that code rather just take the plain js files and concat them (like gulp-concat).

Comment: I'm not sure about the answer to your question since webpack adds code to make dependencies work. If you're ONLY concatting files webpack might be more than you need

Comment: Webpack should have an option to omit it :(

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are using Webpack 4, drop the runtimeChunk to the config file so Webpack will generate a runtime .js file which contains only the webpackBootstrap part, leaving your output file clean:

```
optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: true,
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible using [webpack-merge-and-include-globally](https://github.com/markshapiro/webpack-merge-and-include-globally).

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const MergeIntoSingleFilePlugin = require('webpack-merge-and-include-globally');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: '[name]',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  plugins: [
    new MergeIntoSingleFilePlugin({
      "bundle.js": [
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/util.js'),
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js')
      ],
      "bundle.css": [
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/css/main.css'),
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/css/local.css')
      ]
    })
  ]
};
```

https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/webpack/merge-multiple-javascript-into-single-file-for-global-scope/#webpack-merge-and-include-globally

Comment: I think the options need to be specified under a `file: {}` key (e.g. `new MergeIntoSingleFilePlugin({ file: { ... })`

Answer (score 2):

you should just change the library type of output in webpack.config.js file to `var` like this:

```
    output: {
      library: {
      name: "[name]",
      type: "var" 
           },
     libraryTarget: "umd",
     path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. This `webpack` extra code was breaking my global namespace and my global variables were not working when using then inside my `<script>` tags.

I tried [Desmond Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45619256/4934640) answer but it failed with bunch of errors. To fix, I stopped using `webpack`  and started using `gulp`, `gulp-concat`, `gulp-typescript`:

**packages.json**

```js
{
  "scripts": {
    "gulp": "gulp main"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/gulp": "^4.0.6",
    "@types/gulp-concat",
    "@types/gulp-typescript",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-resolve-dependencies": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-typescript": "^6.0.0-alpha.1",
    "typescript": "^3.7.3"
  }
}
```

**src/someimport.ts**

```js
class SomeClass {
    delay: number;
}
```

**src/main.ts**

```js
/// <reference path="./someimport.ts" />

someclass = new SomeClass();
someclass.delay = 1;
```

This `main` gulp task (on `gulpfile.js`) targets only the `src/main.js` file, resolving all its `/// <reference path=...` include references. These includes are know as `Triple-Slash Directives` and they are used only for transpilers tools to combine files. In our case, they are used explicitly by `.pipe(resolveDependencies({` and by typescript itself when checking the file for missing types, variables, etc.

1. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html
2. [When do I need a triple slash reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22684802/when-do-i-need-a-triple-slash-reference)

Refer to https://github.com/ivogabe/gulp-typescript#api-overview if you would like to customize the `var tsProject = ts.createProject` call and not use a `tsconfig.json` file or override its parameters.

**gulpfile.js**

```js
var gulp = require("gulp");
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var resolveDependencies = require('gulp-resolve-dependencies');

var ts = require("gulp-typescript");
var tsProject = ts.createProject("tsconfig.json");

gulp.task("main", function() {
  return gulp
    .src(["src/main.ts"])
    .pipe(resolveDependencies({
      pattern: /^\s*\/\/\/\s*<\s*reference\s*path\s*=\s*(?:"|')([^'"\n]+)/gm
    }))
    .on('error', function(err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    })
    .pipe(tsProject())
    .pipe(concat('main.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("build/"));
});
```

If you wold like to target all your type script project files instead of only `src/main.ts`, you can replace this:

```js
  return gulp
    .src(["src/main.ts"])
    .pipe(resolveDependencies({
    ...
// -->
  return tsProject
    .src()
    .pipe(resolveDependencies({
    ...
```

If you do not want to use `typescript`, you can use this simplified `gulpfile.js` and remove all `typescript` includes from `package.json`:

**gulpfile.js**

```js
var gulp = require("gulp");
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var resolveDependencies = require('gulp-resolve-dependencies');

gulp.task("main", function() {
  return gulp
    .src(["src/main.js"])
    .pipe(resolveDependencies({
      pattern: /^\s*\/\/\/\s*<\s*reference\s*path\s*=\s*(?:"|')([^'"\n]+)/gm
    }))
    .on('error', function(err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    })
    .pipe(concat('main.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("build/"));
});
```

**packages.json**

```js
{
  "scripts": {
    "gulp": "gulp main"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-resolve-dependencies": "^3.0.1"
  }
}
```

Then, after running the command `npm run gulp`, the file `build/main.js` is created with the following as its contents:

**build/main.js**

```js
class SomeClass {
}
/// <reference path="./someimport.ts" />
someclass = new SomeClass();
someclass.delay = 1;
```

Which allows me to include it in the browser with the `script` tag, after serving the `build` directory files:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            console.log(someclass.delay);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Related questions:

1. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/gulp.html
2. [Can I use the typescript without requireJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36710768/can-i-use-the-typescript-without-requirejs)
3. [Gulp simple concatenation of main file that requires another JS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52338233/gulp-simple-concatenation-of-main-file-that-requires-another-js-file)
4. [Client on node: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined)
5. [How can typescript browser node modules be compiled with gulp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47318837/how-can-typescript-browser-node-modules-be-compiled-with-gulp)
6. [Concatenate files using babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38381621/concatenate-files-using-babel)
7. [How to require CommonJS modules in the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576001/how-to-require-commonjs-modules-in-the-browser)
8. [Is there an alternative to Browserify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34438378/is-there-an-alternative-to-browserify)