# remove webpack webpackBootstrap from the output

Tags: javascript, webpack

How to remove `webpackBootstrap` generated by webpack in the output files

```
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
```

Comment: This is infrastructure code required for `require('blah')` code parts inside your code to work. Why do you want to remove it?

Comment: my requirement is not such. Just a simple conversion with webpack @YuryTarabanko

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43484895/webpack-remove-webpackbootstrap-code

Comment: it doesn't have an accepted answer or working solution I guess @DesmondLua

Comment: @SibiRaj if your purpose is to remove `webpackBootstrap`, `webpack-merge-and-include-globally` works.

Comment: will check that. @DesmondLua