# Remove Webpack bootstrap from output file

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

Well, I know Webpack allow us to import packages with `require` and that's the infrastructure from Webpack.

But, isn't it useless when you don't use `require` in the entry file?

I have this `test.js` entry:

```
console.log('Test');
```

and the output

```
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};
/******/
/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
/******/
/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId]) {
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
/******/        }
/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            i: moduleId,
/******/            l: false,
/******/            exports: {}
/******/        };
/******/
/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
/******/
/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.l = true;
/******/
/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }
/******/
/******/
/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;
/******/
/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;
/******/
/******/    // define getter function for harmony exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.d = function(exports, name, getter) {
/******/        if(!__webpack_require__.o(exports, name)) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, name, {
/******/                configurable: false,
/******/                enumerable: true,
/******/                get: getter
/******/            });
/******/        }
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // getDefaultExport function for compatibility with non-harmony modules
/******/    __webpack_require__.n = function(module) {
/******/        var getter = module && module.__esModule ?
/******/            function getDefault() { return module['default']; } :
/******/            function getModuleExports() { return module; };
/******/        __webpack_require__.d(getter, 'a', getter);
/******/        return getter;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call
/******/    __webpack_require__.o = function(object, property) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property); };
/******/
/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";
/******/
/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = 1);
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ([
/* 0 */,
/* 1 */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

__webpack_require__(2);


/***/ }),
/* 2 */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

console.log('Test');

/***/ })
/******/ ]);
```

This is useless code that also prevents me from using global variables!

At least to me, it is! and that's why I would like to know if there are any plugin or workaround to remove it?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43484895/webpack-remove-webpackbootstrap-code

Comment: Would still like to know if Webpack is capable of outputting bundles without it's module loader bootstrap, as is achievable by Rollup.

Comment: @Robula there is an opened issue about this take a look at it https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2638

Comment: I don't understand why you're using WebPack at all or desire to use global variables. It seems like your project has no need for WebPack or Rollup so you should just remove both of them entirely.

Comment: @sctskw Obviously `console.log('Test');` is not my project :) I needed a transpiler for es6

Comment: @JoseAPL again, I can't stress enough that you don't need WebPack to perform simple transpilation with ES6. All WebPack does is run the babel-cli utility to handle the job. Wouldn't it be easier to just use babel-cli by itself???

Comment: @JoseParedes it's log time ago, but i have the same problem. Did you solve it?

Comment: @Martino I would suggest to use another bundler not webpack which is a more robust and scaffolded bundler

Comment: @JoseParedes which do you suggest?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some research, I couldn't find a proper way to do this.

But investigating for an alternative I could find [`rollupjs`](http://rollupjs.org), an optimized bundler that works as Webpack does, but we can achieve our goal with less code

```
// rollup.config.js
export default {
  input: 'src/main.js',
  output: {
    file: 'bundle.js',
    format: 'cjs'
  }
};
```

It also can be compiled in different formats.

> The format of the generated bundle. One of the following:
>
> - `amd` – Asynchronous Module Definition, used with module loaders like RequireJS
> - `cjs` – CommonJS, suitable for Node and Browserify/Webpack
> - `es` – Keep the bundle as an ES module file
> - `iife` – A self-executing function, suitable for inclusion as a  tag. (If you want to create a bundle for your application,
>     you probably want to use this, because it leads to smaller file
>     sizes.) umd – Universal Module Definition, works as amd, cjs and iife
>     all in one

For further information visit [their documentation](https://rollupjs.org/#quick-start)

## Solution for my question

Using the format `iife`, it encapsulates the scope of my module, so a compiled `test.js` will result in:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

console.log('Test');

}());
```

Which is a more reasonable approach for compiling `ES modules` depending on the output format.

Comment: rollup has a lot of other downsides in comparison with webpack

Comment: Thank you @Jose Paredes

I am out for the same thing. I will have a look at rollupjs. You found the answer yourself and shared it. Nice.

Another thing to people giving answers/comments here. I think it is sad that people give comments and answers that are only oppinions and contra-questions. Either you try to help and give a serious comment answer or you leave it. Thats why I often deside to not put a question here at stackoverflow. Because I know that I will probably get even more frustrated that I already am. Because people come with, as I see it, "stupid" comments or contra-questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to bundle/compress legacy code with rollup.js and don't want an iife, I was able to use the --no-treeshake command-line flag

```
rollup -c --no-treeshake`
```

along with Google closure compiler plugin in order to accomplish this

```
import closure from 'rollup-plugin-closure-compiler-js';
import glob from 'glob';

const inputPath = './Static/JavaScript/';
let configArr = [];

for (let val of glob.sync(inputPath + '*.unpack.js')) {
  let obj = {};
  const filenameRegex = val.match(/([\w\d_-]*)\.?[^\\\/]*$/i);

  obj['input'] = filenameRegex['input'];
  obj['output'] = {
    file: inputPath + filenameRegex[1] + '.js',
    format: 'cjs'
  };
  obj['plugins'] = [closure({
    compilationLevel: 'WHITESPACE_ONLY',
    processCommonJsModules: true,
    languageIn: 'ES5',
    languageOut: 'ES5'
  })]

  configArr.push(obj);
}

export default configArr;
```