# Cleaner webpack module loading for node

Tags: webpack

For my project, I need to deploy "extension scripts" into a vendor managed NodeJS environment that gets run as a part of a pipeline of work at different extension/hook points. My vendor expects a single JS file per "extension point". I found myself repeating functionality so extracted it to files/modules. To assemble the final scripts, I've been developing some WebPack config to inline the local modules. Because the runtime is Node (as opposed to a browser) I don't need the optimisations, or transpilation features. However with my current config, I still have WebPack generating some boilerplate relating to module loading that I don't need but I don't know if, or how to turn it off.

For example

```js
// my-module.js
exports.doSomething = function() { return "something"; }

// my-script.js
const lib = require("lib");
const { doSomething } = require("./my-module");

exports.extension = function() {
  return doSomething().toUpperCase();
}
```

With the following config

```js
module.exports = {
  target: "node",
  mode: "none",
  entry: "my-script.js",
  output: {
    libraryTarget: "commonjs2",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
    filename: "my-script.js"
  },
  externals: [
    require("webpack-node-externals")()
  ]
};
```

WebPack creates:

```js
module.exports =
/******/ (() => { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    var __webpack_modules__ = ([
/* 0 */
/***/ ((__unused_webpack_module, exports, __webpack_require__) => {

const lib = __webpack_require__(1);
const { doSomething } = __webpack_require__(2);

exports.extension = function() {
  return doSomething().toUpperCase();
}

/***/ }),
/* 1 */
/***/ ((module) => {

"use strict";
module.exports = require("lib");;

/***/ }),
/* 2 */
/***/ ((__unused_webpack_module, exports) => {

"use strict";

exports.doSomething = function() {
    return "something";
}

/***/ })
/******/    ]);
/************************************************************************/
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var __webpack_module_cache__ = {};
/******/    
/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
            // ... Omitted for brevity

/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }
/******/    
/************************************************************************/
/******/    // module exports must be returned from runtime so entry inlining is disabled
/******/    // startup
/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(0);
/******/ })()
;
```

Is there a way to make WebPack simply inline the local code without generating the extra module loading boilerplate?

Comment: I think webpack always generates its bootstrapping code. Have you tried looking into `optimization` config? Maybe look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43484895/webpack-remove-webpackbootstrap-code

Perhaps you don't need webpack at all if you just want to automate emitting files from location A to location B.